# Calibrating the Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$f(x)=-x$ and initial condition $x(0)=1$

> Using the Euler Method with the step size $\Delta t=1$, estimate $x(1)$ numerically.

I so far did:

$X_{n+1} = X_n+f(x_n)(1) $

$X_1=0$

$X_2=0 $

I have a similar question on my test tomorrow. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try using a different value for $\Delta t$.

Comment: use $h=\Delta t = 0.1$

Comment: @F'OlaYinka:  but the question specifically asked for $\Delta t=1$

Comment: Actually, wait a second; where's the differential equation?

Comment: @EdGorcenski I was just wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the differential equation you are working with is $x'=-x$ with initial condition $x(0)=1$ and the capital $X$'s are the calculated points.  You have done the iteration correctly, getting $x(1)=0$.  Analytically we can see that the solution is $x=e^{-t}$, so the correct $x(1)=\frac 1e$.  You could redo it with a smaller step size and see that it is more accurate, but that isn't asked for in the question.

Comment: +1 for simply interpreting the question :-) (and for a good answer)